# What is the best way to calculate route summarization?

Tags: networking, router, subnet, sub-network-access-protocol

10.64.0.0/11

10.96.0.0/11

10.128.0.0/11

I have tried 2 methods to calculate route summarization 
each method get different result !

1-Convert the addresses to binary format,then
Count the number of common bits.

10.0100 0000.0.0

10.0110 0000.0.0

10.1000 0000.0.0

---

summarized address = 
10.0.0.0/8

mask = 
255.0.0.0/8

Block size = 
96-64=32

2- 256 – number of networks = subnet mask for summary address.
summarized address is the lowest address .
256-3=253

mask =
255.253.0.0

summarized address =
10.64.0.0

Block size = 
96-64=32

i couldn't determine how many Bits for subnet ?!

Comment: have you got a link to what summarization is?

Comment: See the section about the Largest Common Network in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for how to do that.